# Installing woff font file

Tags: server, fonts, docker

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on a server (docker container) and I need to install fonts programatically. I'm adding the files under `~/.fonts` while it works straightaway with `.ttf` I can't make it to work with `.woff` files.

In the past I have achieved it with Debian 10 by copying the files to the same location with no transformation.

Am I missing something with Ubuntu any package to be installed or do I need to convert the fonts to `.ttf`? And if so what's the recommended method of transforming `woff` into `ttf`?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you will need to convert the `.woff` to a `.ttf` before Ubuntu can use it. A simple way to do this would be to use the `woff2` package that is part of Universe. You can install it like this:

```
sudo apt install woff2
```

Once installed, you can convert a `.woff` to a `.ttf` like this:

```
woff2_decompress fontname.woff2
```

If you would like to convert a `.ttf` to a `.woff`, you can do this:

```
woff2_compress fontname.ttf
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip. The fonts I'm trying to use are not woff2, and when running `woff2_info font.woff` I get `Invalid signature` error. And when doing `woff2_decompress font.woff` no file gets created. I couldn't find any command line package to convert them. Is there any other? I found a python script though.

Comment: This one does not work as the OP clearly states that he wants to convert a `woff` and not a `woff2`.
@pssuils please share the package that you used for people who may one day need it.

Answer (score 1):

This [npm package](https://www.skypack.dev/view/woff-tools) does the job.

Write this

```js
// convertFont.js
const { toSfnt } = require("woff-tools");
const fs = require("fs");

fs.writeFileSync("output.ttf", toSfnt(fs.readFileSync("input.woff")));
```

and call it as usual with `node convertFont.js` works great (if you're not used to npm packages, you need to `npm init` then `npm i woff-tools` first).

The given documentation in the package does not work so well.

Comment: It has a command line interface, so you don't need to create a script. You can do the conversion from the command line after you have installed the package globally with `npm i -g woff-tools`. Just follow the instructions in the docs.